Elasticsearch 8.x Flink Connector Usage Recommendations
I've been trying to make use of the Elasticsearch 8.x Connector which appears to have been completed several months ago per the related ticket in the Apache Flink JIRA.
However, I don't currently see any elasticsearch8-related artifacts when looking through Maven to try and reference and use the updated connector. It doesn't look like it's been released thus far, possibly because it appears to be tied to the elasticsearch-3.1 release (per JIRA). I'm just trying to figure out the best way to go about using it, I think the following options are all on the table:

Use from Maven Directly - Obviously, if the related artifacts were accessible in Maven, this would be ideal, but it doesn't look like those have been officially published yet.
Attempt Compatibility Mode Workaround - Another option might be to attempt to rev the underlying Rest High Level Client used in the latest elasticsearch7 connector to 3.17.x to support the Compatibility Mode options that Elasticsearch details for interop between 7.x and 8.x versions. This feels rather dangerous as any breaking changes between the version implemented by the ES 7.x connector is 3.10.x so it'd be a matter of bumping that ~7 minor versions.
Use 3rd Party Connector Artifacts - I do see that AliBaba appears to have a similar artifact that may contain the necessary bits (com.alibaba.ververica:flink-connector-elasticsearch8), although I'd prefer to use an official release as opposed to a 3rd part.
Fork Connector Bits - The last option that would be least ideal would be forking the existing ES 8.x connector bits and referencing them in my own project(s) until an official release become available.

I think the above would be in order of preference, but I'm curious how others have been using the connector thus far?

Since there wasn't a significant response on the best approach to handle this, I thought I'd follow up with the solution that I used in the interim until the  official release of the Elasticsearch 8.x connector.
Eventual Workaround
In my situation, I still needed to ensure that I retained functionality between both 7.x and 8.x versions of Elasticsearch so I elected to try targeting the Compatibility Mode approach mentioned in the original post which would reduce the number of touchpoints and ensure that compatibility could be retained between the two differing versions.
To accomplish this I did the following three things:

Forked the Elasticsearch Connector Repo - I didn't need the entire repository in this case, primarily just the base and Elasticsearch 7.x connector.
Updated Elasticsearch (and related clients) to 7.17.x - Since the use of compatibility mode requires the Elasticsearch clients to use at least 7.17.x, the underlying versions were required to be updated.
Updated Dependencies - All of the previous dependencies on the Elasticsearch 7.x connector were replaced with this new "bridge" module that would be functionality equivalent (except targeting a newer Elasticsearch version).
Added Appropriate Compatibility Mode Headers to Outbound Requests - Once the dependencies were updated, compatibility mode headers needed to be added to each of the client requests in the Elasticsearch sinks to provide a compatibility mode hint (see below)

Example of Compatibility Mode (and Usage)
/* Example */
public class CompatibilityMode {
    public static void enable(HttpAsyncClientBuilder builder) {
        builder.setDefaultHeaders(COMPATIBILITY_HEADERS);
    }

    /* Example using JSON Headers */
    private static final Set<Header> COMPATIBILITY_HEADERS = new HashSet<Header>() {{
        add(new BasicHeader("Accept", "application/vnd.elasticsearch+json;compatible-with=7"));
        add(new BasicHeader("Content-Type", "application/vnd.elasticsearch+json;compatible-with=7"));
    }};
}

/* Usage */
val builder = ElasticsearchSink.Builder(...)
builder
  .setRestClientFactory { restClient ->
     restClient.setHttpClientConfigCallback { httpAsyncClientBuilder ->
         /* Required Elasticsearch 7.x/8.x Compatibility Headers */
         CompatibilityMode.enable(httpAsyncClientBuilder)
         ...
     }
  }

